# Rotating a UIView by fixed(in any direction) angle using UIRotationGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Guyz...i'm stucked with a silly problem...

I can rotate my UIView using UIRotationGestureRecognizer but just want to rotate it with an fixed angle(for say 45 degree) in any direction considering a threshold value(recognizer.rotation).

Please help me...thanks in advance....

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet works for me

```
-(void)doAction:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){

    float RotationinDegrees = recognizer.rotation * (180/M_PI);
    NSLog(@"Rotation %f",RotationinDegrees);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    if (RotationinDegrees>thresholdValue) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([self transform], DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(desiredangle));
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [recognizer setRotation:0];
}
```

}